# How to backup pictures already deleted?

Tags: android, file-upload

I'm trying to do something similar to what Google+ does on Android, which is to **upload every picture or video taken on the device.**

I've manage to do most of it, the only thing that bedazzled me is that they are able to upload it even if the files are deleted from the device before being uploaded.

The only way that I see to do that, is: when a file is deleted, *retain it's memory address while its still not override by other files*.

To reinforce my belief, I've seen some apps that manage to do something like that for example [Dumpster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baloota.dumpster). So now besides knowing this is possible, I think it's the way that Google does it, but I don't have a clue how...

Can you point me to some information on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: remember that android is basically a unix system (linux, really). it is entirely possible to delete a file in unix and still have apps able to use that file if they'd opened it BEFORE the delete occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned Android is Unix and for that reason it is possible to get information about a file even if it is already deleted.
The main reason for this to happen is because the file is being used by a process and if so, the space claimed by the file before being deleted will be maintained till the last process stops to use the reference to that file.

That is the same reason why 'df' and 'du' shell commands can give you different results. While 'df' shows you that your disk maybe full, 'du' command will show you that you have free space, since the file is no longer visible on the directory tree.

So you can possibly do the same as Google+, by storing references to the "deleted" files, so you can backed them up even after the used deletes it.